# Converting string to float in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, floating-point, type-conversion

I am converting a string like "41.00027357629127", and I am using;

```
Convert.ToSingle("41.00027357629127");
```

or

```
float.Parse("41.00027357629127");
```

These methods return *4.10002732E+15*.

When I convert to float I want "41.00027357629127". This string should be the same...

Comment: How do you know what it is converted to - that is how are you displaying the number

Comment: Any idea why its ToSingle? And not ToFloat?

Comment: 41.00027357629127  shall not be 4.10002732E+15 in scientific notation, unless of course your culture uses decimal comma instead of decimal point (and dot as thousands separator), so the number would actually read: 4100027357629127 consequently become displayed as 4.10002732E+15

Answer (score 276, accepted):

Your thread's locale is set to one in which the decimal mark is "," instead of ".".

Try using this:

```
float.Parse("41.00027357629127", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

Note, however, that a float cannot hold that many digits of precision. You would have to use double or Decimal to do so.

Comment: don't forget to add the namespace `using System.Globalization;` to access `CultureInfo`

Answer (score 34):

You can use the following:

```
float asd = (float) Convert.ToDouble("41.00027357629127");
```

Comment: Please provide some context as to why this is the right answer.

Answer (score 28):

First, it is just a **presentation** of the `float` number you see in the debugger. The *real* value is approximately exact (as much as it's possible).

Note: Use **always** [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) information when dealing with floating point numbers versus strings.

```
float.Parse("41.00027357629127",
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This is just an example; choose an appropriate culture for your case.

Comment: how can ı choose my CultureInfo ? I am in turkey where ı will add TR-TR ?

Comment: @Mehmet `new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR")`

Answer (score 8):

Use `Convert.ToDouble("41.00027357629127");`

[`Convert.ToDouble` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.convert.todouble(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Doesn't this change the datatype from float to double? OP wanted float.

Comment: ust (float) Convert.ToDouble("41.00027357629127"); to convert to float too.

Answer (score 4):

The precision of [float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza) is 7 digits. If you want to keep the whole lot, you need to use the [double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9) type that keeps 15-16 digits. Regarding formatting, look at a post about [formatting doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421520/formatting-doubles-for-output-in-c-sharp). And you need to worry [about decimal separators in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870154/c-sharp-decimal-separator).

Comment: ı tired double.Parse  it returns 4100027357629127.0   it is too bad

Comment: This sounds like the '.' character is not the decimal separator in your locale? Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870154/c-sharp-decimal-separator

Answer (score 2):

A 2022 way of converting an `string` that represents a float value:

```
(float)Convert.ToDecimal(value, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

where you also can choose what kind of float are you expecting to convert, because some `CultureInfo` instances represents decimal values with a `,` and others with `.`.

If you need more decimals to obtain more precision, just not use `float`

```
Convert.ToDecimal(value, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `double.Parse("41.00027357629127");`

Comment: I don't think he's asking how to round it.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to using **System.Globalization** to dealing convertions from string to float/double/decimal without problem.

Then you can call *Parse* on *float*(or *double/decimal* depending at the accuracy you need), and as argument in Parse you need your *string* (you can store it in a variable if you want) and **CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat**

So, as previous users already explained:

```
float.Parse("41.00027357629127", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32416679)

Answer (score -2):

You can use parsing with double instead of float to get more precision value.