# Is there any way in unity for number recognition?

Tags: unity-game-engine, numbers, image-recognition

I am trying to create a AR app which recognizes numbers.I was able to do the text recognition using vuforia but numbers I didn't find any such SDK.I am also ready to write the code using c# but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Could you use Text recognition and convert to a number? Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202673/converting-string-to-float-in-c-sharp

Comment: I am not able to detect the numbers string also.