# Get data from InputField and Multiply by Float? (Unity/C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was working on a code and got an issue. What I'm trying to do is to use InputField in unity, then use that number to multiply by existing float. Here's what I got so far:

```
private float finePrice = 0.0001f;
public InputField enterValue;

public Text estimatedValue;

estimatedValue.text = string.Format ("{0}", finePrice * enterValue);
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Operator `*' cannot be applied to operands of type `float' and `UnityEngine.UI.InputField'
```

In my understanding is that I cannot multiply string (inputfield) to float? I tried changing Content Type of Input Field to "Decimal Number" but I'm getting the same error. Tried googling it, nothing to be found. Please help? I'm lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the content of the `InputField` using the [`text` property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-text.html), and then convert that content to `float` because it's a string:

```
private float finePrice = 0.0001f, valueEntered;
public InputField enterValue;

public Text estimatedValue;

if(float.TryParse(enterValue.text, out valueEntered))
{
    estimatedValue.text = (finePrice * valueEntered).ToString();
} 
else
{
    estimatedValue.text = "Please enter a float value";
}
```

Note I've used `float.TryParse` so that if the user entered a value that can't be converted to `float` you will simply get `false` instead of an exception you would get if you used `float.Parse`. Also, I've changed your `string.Format` to simply `ToString` - There is no point of using `string.Format` in cases like this.

Comment: BTW, I know nothing about unity, but I do know c#. I've simply googled `UnityEngine.UI.InputField` since the class name made it clear to me that it represents some sort of a `TextBox` and it should have a `Text` or `Content` property - which it does. Should you want to be a programmer, the single most important thing you should learn is how to use search engines.

Comment: That makes sense because it doesn't work, lol?

if(float.TryParse(enterValue.Text already isn't working because code can't see reference to enterValue. At least the way you wrote it.

Comment: @papi I've copied your code as the base of my own. Of course it this case there reference named `enterValue` points to `null` - I assumed you only wrote it like this so we would know what types are involved...

Comment: what do you mean? I just went using your own example as of Im trying to understand the way you've done it.... I tried all I can, thats why Im here. Asking for help. A little confusing.

Comment: `enterValue` should refenrece an instance of `InputField` that actually exists in your UI, and `estimatedValue` should refenrece and instance of `Text` in your UI. They can't be just declared and used without being set first. That's very basic stuff. You should probably consult a c# tutorial.

Comment: @papi I've made a small edit to this answer, try it now.

Answer (score 2):

Like [Zohar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134587/3785314) mentioned, `InputField.text` is a `string` and you need to convert that to `float` before you multiply it with your other `float`.

I left my own answer because I think it's better to use `float.Parse` to make that conversion and pass in `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat` to the second parameter as you don't know what culture the user's device is set to.

Convert `InputField` value to `float`

```
float inputInFloatFormat = float.Parse(enterValue.text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

Multiply by your `float` finePrice variable

```
float multiplyResult = inputInFloatFormat * finePrice;
```

Display result on your text component(Convert multiplyResult to string) then display it

```
estimatedValue.text = multiplyResult.ToString();
```

Comment: Then you would have to wrap your `float.Parse` with a `try...catch`, while the [`float.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) page specifically states that *"The s parameter is parsed using the formatting information in a NumberFormatInfo object that is initialized for the current system culture."* meaning it's parsed according to the culture initialized by the device - so there's a very good chance that's the culture the user is using... BTW, there is an overload of `TryParse` that takes `NumberStyles` and `IFormatProvider` as parameters...

Comment: error CS0103: The name `CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context? What is that even? I never heard of it.

Update: Oh, I had to using System.Globalization;
Got it.

Comment: @Programmer I'm getting an error "error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `mScript.enterValue'"

Comment: @ZoharPeled I just realized `TryParse` has a second parameter for that so OP can use your `TryParse`  but provided the second parameter from my answer or just use `Parse` in my answer but inside `try/catch`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11203062/3785314) for why I used `NumberFormat` instead of the default one. I used that so that "." is supported.

Comment: @papi You did not copy my code correctly. I did a test on my side and it compiles. Please try re-copying it again just like it is. Also, if that doesn't help, edit your question and add EDIT to it. Add the new code from my answer that doesn't work and I will see what you did wrong.