# Parsing String to Float returns incorrect result

Tags: c#, string, floating-point

I try to convert a String to a Float in C#. I tried all variants found in [Converting String To Float in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202673) but i get the wrong result anyways.

I tried

```
float.Parse((string)parameter);
float.Parse((string)parameter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
float.Parse((string)parameter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
(float)Convert.ToDouble((string)parameter);
```

and all of these variants without the (string) cast. I get no compiler error but the result is wrong. When i use `Math.sin(convertedParameter)` then for `3.14159` i get the result `2,535182E-06`

**Edit** When i put `3,14159` as input i get `-0,2622557` - maybe that helps.

Comment: what's your input string?

Comment: Its in the last line of my question - 3.14159

Comment: Which result is wrong? `convertedParameter` or `Math.Sin(convertedParameter)`? If you want float, why are you using `Convert.ToDouble` instead of `Convert.ToSingle`?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Be sure to include the inputs you are using (in C# code) and the **exact result you are expecting for that input** (as well as the result you actually received).

Comment: I still don't understand what result you want. Could you please show us your input and expected output?

Comment: Ok again: Input 3,14159 and i expect (of course) the correct result of 0.00000265358 like here https://www.google.com/search?q=sin(3.14159)

Comment: Ii also tried with `result*(180 /Math.PI)`

Comment: I tried `Console.WriteLine(convertedParameter.ToString("G10"));` and scan see that it becomes `3.14159012` due to the inaccuracies with floating point values. Comparing your .NET value with the value from Google yields a difference of around `1.6E-9` (`1.6 x 10^-9`), so this seems to be a non-issue.

Comment: Also, note that `double PI = double.Parse(Math.PI.ToString());` then `Math.Sin(PI)` and `Math.Sin(Math.PI)` will give two different results. `Math.PI` has a +2 precision. The difference may seem very large if you ignore the `-16`.

Comment: Thank you i definitely have to focus more on math.

Comment: @John thank you when i use 19.84 for e.g the results are equal. But shouldnt something around of PI be the accuratest?

Comment: You have to remember that floating point values can only accurately represent fractional values composed of 1/2ⁿ (e.g. 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, etc.) or combinations thereof (e.g. 0.75, etc), because it has to be represented in binary. Values that fall outside this are represented as an approximation, thus calculations are based upon that approximation. See [here](https://floating-point-gui.de/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.535182E-06 means 2.535182 * 0.000001 which equals 0.000002535182.
So you're getting the right result, I think you're just ignoring the E-06 at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think your question is not about the float result but the string format. 2.535182E-06 is equal to 0.00000265358, just in another display form. You can use string.Format method to get what format you would like.

```
string.Format("{0:F11}",Math.Sin(3.14159))
```

Comment: Sorry, that wasnt my intention because i want to return a float value for further calculations but it is also helpful to me. +1

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working perfectly fine but your pi's accuracy is not that good to result to a number very close to zero. If you use this value you have to use a tolerance of 10^-5. Using `3.14159265359` for example, will result in a tolerance of 10^-12.

Also `2.535182E-06` is the scientific notation for `0.000002535182`.

Comment: When i try `3.14159265359` i get `-8,742278E-08` on google i get `-2.0682311e-13` https://www.google.com/search?q=sin(3.14159265359) that is not the same in just another notation is it?

Comment: Ok when i try 19.84 i get the same results, so i think its about inaccuracy +1

Comment: @DoJo also keep in mind that google and C# may be using different implementations to calculate trigonometric functions. So it is possible that the numbers are not 100% the same. The point is though that their relative difference is negligible, because especially in the case that you're testing, we compare really really small numbers, which unless you do highly precise mathematical computations (where in this case you would use a pi with a huge decimal part) you should be fine on any other application.