# How do I convert a string to a float?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've looked around here a bit, but all the solutions that seem like they should work are not working for me. I have a string of text being entered into an input field. I want to convert that string to a float so that the user can enter a monetary value like "234.34".

I have already tried the following:

```
try
{
    float number = (float) Convert.ToDouble(_accountAmountInput.text);
}catch(Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log(e + "\n must be number");
}
```

AND

```
try
{
    float number = float.Parse(_accountAmountInput.text);
}catch(Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log(e + "\n must be number");
}
```

AND

```
if(float.TryParse(_accountAmountInput.text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture, out float number))
{
    Debug.Log("Number: " + number);
}
else
{
    //display error screen
    //account amount needs to be digits only
}
```

The last one outputs the correct number but I still get an error message
I'm always entering a valid float value.

The error message I'm always getting is :

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str,
>   System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer&
>   number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean
>   parseDecimal) (at <1f0c1ef1ad524c38bbc5536809c46b48>:0)

Comment: Instead of `InstalledUICulture` use `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Some cultures use `,` as the fractional portion separator. Try to simplify the code until you get it to work. `float number = float.Parse("1.2");` or `float number = float.Parse("1,2");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting String To Float in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202673/converting-string-to-float-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You may be using one of cultures like french where the decimal separator isnt `.`. You can confirm this by checking integer number works with your code.

Comment: changing to InvariantCulture worked for me, Thanks!

Comment: And, don't "try-parse-catch" use "if-tryparse" instead. Exception handling is costly, don't use it unless you have no other option.

Answer (score 1):

`float` is alias for `Single`, just use `Convert.ToSingle`