# How to convert string with comma to float in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, type-conversion, typeconverter

```
var withComma = Convert.ToSingle("3,2");
Console.WriteLine($"Converted float from string with comma (3,2): {withComma}");
```

It returns to the console:

```
Converted float from string with comma (3,2): 32
```

But should return:

```
Converted float from string with comma (3,2): 3.2
```

How can I convert it to float and make the result to be 3.2?

Comment: Use `float.Parse()` or `float.TryParse()` with the appropriate [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo).

Comment: Is this a European number?  Maybe pass along a format provider as the second argument to `Convert.ToSingle(String, IFormatProvider)` or set the _culture_ on the current thread

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202673/converting-string-to-float-in-c-sharp/11203062#11203062

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting String To Float in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202673/converting-string-to-float-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @eocron No, it don't work

Answer (score 0):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/TnQyL9

```
Console.WriteLine(float.Parse("3,2", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES")));
```

prints: `3.2`

There is a lot of cultures which have this format. Just pick one you are fine with.

Comment: But then if I will try with the "3.2" instead of "3,2" it will return 32, I need something that will work for both scenarios

Comment: You do realize that you have multiple formats:  3,000.1 and 3.000,1 ? You need to know culture beforehand for correct parsing. If you can't distinguish I think you need some custom heuristic to distinguish (replace like in other answer, or assume that last separator is float separator, which comes with pros/cons and hard to debug error)

Comment: @SValley_Dev If you're in the situation where you don't know whether "1,000" means one thousand or `1.0`, then your data needs to be sanitised.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I know what it means, but different clients can use different cultures on their machine and I don't know what value will come to me in format with dot or in format with comma

Comment: @SValley_Dev do you have access to client code? You can send culture in http headers if they are not already sent - HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().AcceptLanguage. Believe me, you are not the first one who deal with multicultural systems and there is already handy ways to manage those. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language

Answer (score -1):

Finally I'm using this approach

```
private void convertToFloat(string str) 
{
    float result = float.Parse(str.Replace(',', '.'));
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```