# UiPath - parse numeric string with thousands separator from excel to number

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I am quite new to RPA and want to parse and want to parse some excel values to a number format.

The numbers in this excel are interpreted as text and looking like this           `1.500.000,00`
Note that there are some spaces at the beginning and dots as thousands separator.

Now in UiPath, I want to read the value, convert them into a double or float and write back to excel.

I've tried to replace spaces and dots by `""`, so only the number with a decimal comma is left.
[image]

This works, but the cell is still formatted as text.
[image]

How to format an excel cell as number in UiPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#:

```
float.Parse("1500000,00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

Additionally have a look here: [Converting String To Float in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202673/converting-string-to-float-in-c-sharp)