# convert float to string with . instead of ,

Tags: c#

> "How to convert a float to a string with exactly one decimal"

This question has been asked many times, and the usual answer is `MyFloat.ToString("0.0")` or something similar. However, the problem I am facing with this is that

```
float f = 1;
string s = f.ToString("0.0");
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

outputs `1,0` but what I need is `1.0`. I could of course manually replace the comma with a dot afterwards, but I'm pretty sure that that wouldn't be the proper way to do it.
I wasn't able to find a solution on the internet because everywhere it says that this already outputs `1.0`
How come?

Comment: and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160059/set-up-dot-instead-of-comma-in-numeric-values), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870154/c-sharp-decimal-separator) ...

Answer (score 7):

You can use `InvariantCulture` with `ToString`:

```
string s = f.ToString("0.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Decimal separator depends on the culture but `InvariantCulture` uses `.` which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use for example InvariantCulture

```
string s = f.ToString("0.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic solution is: to change `NumberDecimalSeparator` in current culture:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
float value1 = 3.55f;
String message = String.Format("Value is {0}", value1); 
Console.Write(message); //--> "Value is 3.55"
```