# Comma instead of dot from some operations

Tags: c#

So for example if you run: `(Math.Round(100 * (4666 / (double)82343), 2))` on rextester.com it returns `5,67` instead of `5.67` how can I make sure this operation and this operation ONLY returns a dot (while leaving it as , for everything else)

I don't want to .replace it in case other characters are possibly used like  (space) which i've seen used before.

Comment: This is a matter of globalization. In the Culture rextester uses, the decimal point is represented with a comma.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert float to string with . instead of ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374167/convert-float-to-string-with-instead-of)

Comment: Math.Round() never formats a floating pointer number.  Don't get confused by what the debugger or a random website shows you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as format provider

```
var result = (Math.Round(100 * (4666 / (double)82343), 2));
var output = result.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

By default .Net application uses local machine culture information.
By providing custom culture you can change this behaviour.

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is a predefined culture which has a dot `.` as `NumberDecimalSeparator`

Comment: Thank you knew it was CultureInfo related but didn't know exactly how to handle this operation. Thank you