# explain the two approach String Type Casting In C#

Tags: c#, string, casting

Can anyone please explain me what is the difference between these two string Type Casting method.

**Type 1**

```
int i = 90;
string b = i.ToString();
```

**Type 2**

```
int i = 90;
string b = Convert.ToString(i);
```

I want to know the major difference of using the two different approach. The 1st one is to handle the null value,we can use '`Convert.ToString();` '. And moreover I get to know that '`.ToString()`' can be override.
Can anyone can explain how. And which one is good to use.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326060/variable-tostring-vs-convert-tostringvariable

http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/36308

Comment: .ToString() does not handle null value

Comment: Neither of those are parsing. Both are *formatting*.

Comment: @Arshad: How do you expect an `int` value to be null?

Comment: @Arshad: Well again, ToString isn't parsing, and as this is a call to `int.ToString()`, there's no possibility of it being null...

Comment: Also related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ca084595-8502-4efe-b4be-d52ccb7d63c4/converttostring-vs-tostring?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @JonSkeet, I mean to say in terms of parsing reference types

Comment: @Arshad: Yet *again*, this isn't parsing - and introducing a comparison with a different method not mentioned in the question doesn't feel terribly useful to me.

Comment: Also from [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x70d7t0y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); _This implementation is identical to `Int32.ToString()`. It formats value by using the formatting conventions of the current thread culture._

Comment: The amount of characters to type. And for sure the type itself. Its extension vs. method I would say.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I want to know the major difference of using the two different approach. The 1st one is to handle the null value 'Convert.ToString(); ' is good. And moreover I get to know that '.ToString()' can be override.
Can anyone can explain how.